# What is the fastest way of selecting by a list of strings in sqlite database?

Tags: sqlite

I have database with with roughly following structure:

table1 (name) -< table2 -< table3 (score)

where -< means 1 to many relationship. What i need to do is for every string in a given list find the linked entry from table3 with a maximum score value. The way i do it now is quite slow, and i wonder of it could be sped up.

How i am doing this:

```
SELECT k.score,k.yaw,k.pitch,k.roll,k.kp_number,k.ke_number,k.points,k.elems --various fields of third table
FROM File 
JOIN FaceDetection AS d ON d.f_id=File.file_id --joining second table
JOIN FaceKey AS k ON k.face_det=d.fd_id --joining third table
WHERE name=:fld 
ORDER BY k.score DESC
```

I open transaction, prepare query with the above text, and in cycle retrieve the entries i am interested in from the database, then commit transaction. What are better, faster ways?

Comment: Your query seems fine. The database does a lot of optimization itself. You transaction call has to be that way too. I see no way to make this more efficient.

Comment: can you put the `WHERE` condition as an `AND` condition of the `ON`?

Comment: Have you put indexes on the ID fields?

Comment: The answer i wanted i eventually got [here][1].

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18184392/how-to-get-key-of-the-maximal-record-in-group

Answer (score 1):

Indexes can be used for all the columns that are used for lookups or sorting, but a query cannot use more than one index per table.

Check the [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) output to see whether this query does table scans or uses indexes.

You are not returning values from any table but `FaceKey`, so you do not actually need to do a join.
However, rewriting the query as below might or might not help:

```
SELECT score,
       yaw,
       pitch,
       roll,
       kp_number,
       ke_number,
       points,
       elems
FROM FaceKey
WHERE face_det IN (SELECT fd_id
                   FROM FaceDetection
                   WHERE f_id IN (SELECT file_id
                                  FROM File
                                  WHERE name = :fld))
ORDER BY score DESC
```