# How to get key of the maximal record in group?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables in my database, one holds the names of files, and other holds records of information described in them, inincluding sizes of sections. it can be descrived as:

Table1: id as integer, name as varchar

Table2: recid as integer primary key, file_id as integer, score as float

Between the tables there is an one-to-many link, from Table1.id to table2.file_id. What i need is for every file which name matches a certain pattern retrieve the id of the linked record with the maximum score and the score itself.
So far i have used:

```
SELECT name,MAX(score)
FROM Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.file_id=Table1.id
WHERE name LIKE :pattern
GROUP BY name
```

but i cannot retrieve the id of the record in Table2 this way.

The dialect i am using is Sqlite.

What query should be used to retrieve data on the record that has maximum score for every file?

Update:

With this query, i am getting close to what i want:

```
SELECT name,score,recid
FROM Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON file_id=id 
WHERE name LIKE :pattern
GROUP BY name 
HAVING score=MAX(score)
```

However, this leaves out the entries in the first table that have no corresponding entries in the second table out. How can i ensure they are in the end result anyway? Should i use UNION, and if so - how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can actually be achieved without a `GROUP BY` by using a brilliantly simple technique described by @billkarwin [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column#answer-123481):

```
SELECT name, t2.score
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.file_id = t1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 t2copy ON t2copy.file_id = t2.file_id
                             AND t2.score < t2copy.score
WHERE name LIKE :pattern
  AND t2copy.score IS NULL
```

See [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/7c0b8/3).

Comment: Agreed - shame I can't really take credit for it. One of those where it's obvious *once you've seen it*!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you must use a subquery

```
SELECT name, recid, score
FROM Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.file_id=Table1.id
WHERE name LIKE :pattern AND score = (SELECT MAX(score) FROM Table2.score)
```

Comment: This will return entries with score equal to the maximum score in the whole of table 2, not in the groupings

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT name, recid, score
FROM Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Table2
     ON Table2.file_id=Table1.id
WHERE name LIKE :pattern AND
      score = (SELECT MAX(t2.score)
               FROM Table1 t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    Table2 t2 
                    ON t2.file_id=t1.id
               where t1.name = table1.name
              );
```

Note that you need table aliases to distinguish the tables in the inner query from the outer query.  I am guessing which tables the columns are actually coming from.